# How to export database from homestead box?

Tags: mysql, doctrine, vagrant, symfony4, homestead

I'm setting up completed project's environment on new machine.
I have developed project with vagrant and homestead box. Currently I'm not planning to isolate project but only running it on new machine. The goal of mine is export MySQL database from that vagrant box and import it to the new system. How can I export database and import it to new machine?

Comment: have you tried to ssh into the vagrant box ('vagrant ssh' from the project directory) and just doing a mysqldump from there ? you can dump to one of the shared directories or scp/rsync the dumped file to you host computer and the simply import it on your new machine

Comment: Thanks, it has worked out perfectly fine. But there is the additional step should be done as well. Within homestead.yaml file mapping have to be mentioned,otherwise database will only be  dumped within VM machine.

Comment: Ok good to hear !

Comment: @ElshanAkberov - for the benefit of future users, could you put your solution as an answer to this question?

Answer (score 0):

1. As @Dennisdebest suggested, You should SSH into the Homested box

   1. `homestead ssh` if you set the homestead alias in you bash settings file, OR
   2. `cd` into your Homestead directory, e.g. `cd ~/Homestead`, and run `vagrant ssh`
2. Run `mysqldump` to extract the data

   1. `mysqldump -u <user> -p <database_name> [<table_name>] > path/to/file.sql` - this will copy all the MYSQL data of the database **database_name** to the **path/to/file.sql** file. Notice that the **table_name** is optional and you should use if you want to export data from only one specific table.
   2. you'll be prompted to input your DB password

Note: don't type your password in the `mysqldump` command because it will understand it as a database name. Type when requested - right after you run the `mysqldump` command

#### Troubleshooting

If for some reason you don't have mysqldump installed in your Vagrant box, install it using `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install mysql-client` command, but usually it comes installed with the Homestead box.